# Double Buffering in Visual Basic Six

Tags: vb6

Right now I am trying to make a small game. But my graphics such as rectangles etc. are flickering. I heard you can use double buffering in visual basic 6 but I cant find the code for it. Does anybody have the code for it?

Answer (score 0):

A quick, simple Google search for "Double Buffering VB6" leads to this link: http://compsci.ca/v3/viewtopic.php?t=16179 Another good source is: http://bfy.tw/3EPl :-)